# Exporting MySql data to CSV but getting UTC date

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to export all the data from MySql to CSV using php, everything is working fine but the date is which is being returned seems to be in UTC. I have tried to covert in IST but its not working.

```
if(isset($_POST['from_date']) && isset($_POST['to_date'])){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `".$tblname."` WHERE (DATE(convert_tz(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_field),'+00:00','+05:30')) BETWEEN '".$from_date."' and '".$to_date."') ORDER BY id ASC";
}
```

here is the timestamp of the date

```
1632019768
```

and its returning 18-09-2021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always do the conversion with php on the value:

```
<?php
$timeStamp = "1632019768";
$date = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timeStamp);
echo "Timestamp to utc: " . $date . "<br><br>";

echo "Add 5 hours and 30 mins: " .  date("Y-d-m H:i:s", strtotime($date.' +5 hours + 30 min'));
```

which will return :

```
Timestamp to utc: 2021-09-19 02:49:28

Add 5 hours and 30 mins: 2021-19-09 08:19:28
```

Comment: hey! thanks for the answer. is it possible to convert that while passing the mysql query? and could you please tell me how can I use that function "strtotime" on  $date = date("Y-m-d",$row['date_field']);   should I use it on date_field or first store that in variable then convert it?

Comment: Hey Buddy! thanks for your help I figured that out by implementing what you have suggested .

Comment: $row['date_field'] is the $timeStamp value in my example - you turn it in the a standard utc date with the gmdate - like the example and than you use strtotime to conver it to whatever you need.

Comment: @HemantGiri You can mark useful than! :) happy to help!